# Is repeatedly using the value as an int in separate for loop bad practice?

Tags: java, for-loop

Very simple question, but I can't find an answer anywhere. Common coding practice has a for loop with i as an int, as in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i++)
```

If you have nested for loops, you obviously need your inner loop(s) to have different variable names, to differentiate between them.

However, if you have multiple for loops in one method, that aren't nested, is it bad practice to declare each of them as int i? I know that they have no scope outside of that particular declaration, so I know it won't cause any errors, but is it good practice?

****Edit:***
Hi all. Thanks for your fantastic (and extremely prompt!) answers. I wish I could have chosen all as answers. I didn't think it was bad practice, just wanted to be sure. Thanks for all your help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't  considered a bad practice,you can name the variables same (there'd be no compiler errors),  because, those variables are only confined within that block .in fact, widely used loop variables are named like `i`,`j`,`k`, `a`,`b`

Answer (score 1):

If they aren`t nested, then there will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not bad practice. `i` is the traditional variable name for the loop index. You should ask yourself if a method that contains multiple loops doesn't do too many things, though, and should not be splitted into several methods.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's scoped to the loop (i.e. defined in the for statement) then it's not bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly Good to use int i in sequentiell for Loops. As Long as they are defined inside the Loop. 

If you use it the otherway it is more prone to bugs.